# Cordova build errror

Tags: cordova

I use cordova and Android Studio.

PS C:\cordova\cordova-project>cordova --version
9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)

Android SDK Build-Tools 19.1.0 and 28.0.3
Android SDK Platform-Tools 28.0.3
Android SDK Tools 26.1.1

when I run the build I get an error:

PS C:\cordova\cordova-project> cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED)
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 stopped Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

  > Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3
  >   .3.0.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.p
  >   om'.
  >   Connect to dl.google.com:443 [dl.google.com/74.125.131.190, dl.google.com/74.125.131.136, dl.google.com
  >   /74.125.131.93, dl.google.com/74.125.131.91] failed: Connection timed out: connect
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.3.0/gradle-3.3.0.pom'.
  >   Connect to jcenter.bintray.com:443 [jcenter.bintray.com/35.157.207.108, jcenter.bintray.com/54.93.138.2
  >   18] failed: Connection timed out: connect
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with
  --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 9s
C:\cordova\cordova-project\platforms\android\gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Comment: PS C:\cordova\cordova-project> cordova platform ls
Installed platforms:
  android 8.0.0
Available platforms:
  browser ^6.0.0
  electron ^1.0.0
  ios ^5.0.0
  osx ^5.0.0
  windows ^7.0.0

Comment: PS C:\Gradle\gradle-3.3\bin> gradle -v

 ------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 3.3
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2017-01-03 15:31:04 UTC
Revision:     075893a3d0798c0c1f322899b41ceca82e4e134b

Groovy:       2.4.7
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM:          1.8.0_211 (Oracle Corporation 25.211-b12)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

Comment: You might be on a restricted network, which does not allow to access the download links. HTTP-Proxy with authentication maybe. Try to access the files via browser. If that works, maybe you can try to download them via command line.

Comment: can you `cordova clean android ` and try again ? 
As a last resort , remove the android platform and build again.

Comment: I accessed the files through the browser. But how do I install the required packages using the command line?

Comment: Thanks, Dirk! My proxy blocked requests.